# CDI Beans not retaining values

Tags: java, jsf, cdi

I'm working on a large JSF project but have noticed that none of my session beans are retaining their values. In order to try and find my error I created a test project with a simple injection, however I am still finding the session scoped bean is not retaining its values.

I have searched through stackoverflow.com (and spent several hours on Google) for an answer but cannot find one. I would be very grateful for any help.

I am using JSF 2.2, Netbeans 7.3.1 & Glassfish Server 4.0

The code for my simple test project is below.

### beans.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

### index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText value="#{bean1.title}" />
            <h:commandButton action="#{bean2.test()}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

### Bean1.java

```
package beans;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;


@Named(value = "bean1")
@SessionScoped
public class Bean1 implements Serializable {

    public Bean1() {
    }

    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

### Bean2.java

```
package beans;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Named(value = "bean2")
@RequestScoped
public class Bean2 {

    public Bean2() {
    }

    @Inject
    Bean1 b1;

    public String test()
    {
        System.out.println(b1.getTitle());

        return null;
    }   
}
```

Comment: @VasilLukach I understand that `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` is the import required for ManagedBeans whereas Named beans (CDI beans) should use `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`

Comment: What version of JSF are you using?  How is your application deployed?

Comment: @JohnAment I am using JSF 2.2, Netbeans 7.3.1 & Glassfish Server 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess, your CDI 1.0 beans.xml is causing confusion in the app server.  Try upgrading to a CDI 1.1 beans.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
   bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks @JohnAment that has fixed the simple test project. Unfortunately it hasn't fixed the issue in the larger project which I am working on despite both projects having identical configuration. At least I now know it is an issue within my project though.

Comment: Ok, if you want to post more of your big project feel free.

Comment: I have narrowed down the problem to being use of jsf templates. Are templates not compatible with CDI beans? For some reason when I use the templates the session beans appear to expire after the request is finished but when I remove the templates the session beans work as expected. Is this something you have heard of before @JohnAment?

Comment: The one weird thing is the way you're separating request scoped and session scoped objects.  Is it possible for you to put the bean with the values in a session scoped object and call a method on the session scoped?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you mean @JohnAment. The session scoped bean is a user bean which contains information about the current user. The request bean is used primarily to take user input from the view to the model where it is processed and added to a database. I chose request scope for this as it only needs to exist for the life of the request. The injection is required because I need to record the data in the database against the correct user record. Is this poor design to have 2 separate beans with different scopes?